# Simple get request with node.js and express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch-api

I have tried everything and can't figure out what i am doing wrong. I have no problem posting data from the client to the server but the other way around i can't get it to work.

The only response i get in my client is `ReadableByteStream {}`.

This is my code on the client:

```
export function getAllQuestionnairesAction(){
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    dispatch(getAllQuestionnairesRequest());

    return fetch(API_ENDPOINT_QUESTIONNAIRE)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          console.log(res.body)
          return dispatch(getAllQuestionnairesSuccess(res.body));
        } else {
          throw new Error("Oops! Something went wrong");
        }
      })
      .catch(ex => {
        return dispatch(getAllQuestionnairesFailure());
      });
  };
}
```

This is my code on the server:

```
exports.all = function(req, res) {
  var allQuestionnaires = [];

  Questionnaire.find({}).exec(function(err, questionnaires) {

    if(!err) {
      console.log(questionnaires)
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.send(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
      //res.json(questionnaires)
    }else {
      console.log('Error in first query');
      res.status(400).send(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What version / polyfill of fetch are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing some guesswork here, since I'm not sure what flavor of `fetch` you are currently using, but I'll take a stab at it based on the standard implementation of `fetch`.

The `response` inside the resolution of `fetch` typically does not have a directly readable `.body`. See [here](https://github.com/github/fetch#json) for some straight forward examples.

Try this:

```
export function getAllQuestionnairesAction(){
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    dispatch(getAllQuestionnairesRequest());

    return fetch(API_ENDPOINT_QUESTIONNAIRE)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Oops! Something went wrong");
        }
      })
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json); // response body here
        return dispatch(getAllQuestionnairesSuccess(json));
      })
      .catch(ex => {
        return dispatch(getAllQuestionnairesFailure());
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: im using https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch and https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise

Comment: I think that confirms my suspicion -- see how they have `return response.json();` in isomorphic-fetch's examples. See if my suggestion works for you. The important part is the `return res.json()` and then expecting body as the promise resolution in the second `.then()`.

Comment: Perfekt thanks, it works. 
Im new to all these technologies and have trouble find information about stuff like that. Im using a boilerplate for starting help and there they used those Libraries. Do you have any source where i can read about this fetch stuff ?

Comment: @DanielStorch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch is one good place to start.